# Android , My program Crash because that stuck on the while loop

Tags: android

i checked it and every time i am trying to run the project 
that make my app to crash ...
that stack on the while loop.. 
and don't exit from the loop

the main code :

```
package com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo";
    private TextView tvData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "1");

        Button btnHit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
        tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);
        Log.i(TAG,"2");
        btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new JsonTask().execute("http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
                Log.i(TAG,"2");

            }
        });
    }



    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG,"3");

            //connecting to the Server
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            Log.i(TAG,"3.1");

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                Log.i(TAG, params[0]+"");
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.i(TAG, "3.15");
                connection.connect();
                Log.i(TAG, "3.2");


                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                //that will take the strem from the connection and
                //stoage that on the stream object

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = reader.readLine();
                Log.i(TAG,"4");

                //the line is read the line from the Buffer Reader
                //and add it to the StringBuffer
                while ((line != null)) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"5");
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                tvData.setText(result);

            }


    }
/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
}
```

the error log 
:

```
12-08 05:06:05.854 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 57283554-byte allocation.
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo, PID: 16934
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo.MainActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:95)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo.MainActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
12-08 05:06:05.858 16934-16990/com.example.omermalka.jasonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

thanks for all the helpers !!

Comment: `ClassCastException: http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

Comment: what that intention ? what should i do ?

Comment: Use `https://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt` and if http is supported then why not using `HttpURLConnection ` instead of `HttpsURLConnection ` ?

Comment: i understand .. ty , i have more bug , my loop is No final she don't stop until its make the app crash

Comment: @omermalka: Which loop?

Comment: while loop "
 while ((line != null)) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"5");
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

Comment: You are getting an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`... Maybe the file you are downloading is too large to fit in your memory?

Comment: the the file
https://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt
he is really small one

Comment: @omermalka: see following post [How to send an HTTP request from Android using HttpURLConnection](http://syntx.io/how-to-send-an-http-request-from-android-using-httpurlconnection/) how read data from Stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change HttpsURLConnection to HttpURLConnection

as your link is http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt

and put readLine() in while condition.

```
    while (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"5");
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }
```